# Steampunk movie about demons and apocalypse

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie once and forget the title. It is about:

- alternate history, set in steam/dieselpunk setting
- megacorporations fighting over the world
- some demon-monsters from under the earth
- group of heroes set to fight and stop the demon plague
- they're flying in some steampunk alike airship

It was "A book of demons", or probably something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mutant Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0490181/), (2008):

> At the end of the Ice Age, The Machine came from outer space with the
>   purpose to change men into mutants. However, a hero defeated the
>   device and a great seal was laid over The Machine. In 2707, the
>   depleted world is ruled by four Corporations: Mishima, Bauhaus,
>   Capitol and Imperial that are in a constant state of war. During a
>   battle between Capitol and Bauhaus, the great seal is broken and The
>   Machine works again transforming soldiers and civilians into hordes of
>   mutants.

It did have an airship that looked like it was steam-powered.